# iOSアプリをXcode、Swiftで作成中。エラーを解決出来ない

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

1ヶ月ほど前からYouTubeでアプリ開発を学習中の超初心者です。
こちらへ質問させて頂くのも初めてです。

#### エラーに至るまでの経緯

1. Google Mapの機能を入れるためにターミナルを使って操作した
2. Rubyのバージョンを3.3.0へ変更した
3. Cocoapodsをインストールした
4. Swiftのファイル@mainがあるファイルにGoogle MapのAPIキーを入れて準備を完了させた
5. プレビューエラーが発生するようになった

お手数おかけしますが解決方法をご教授頂けると大変助かります。

#### エラー内容

```
== DATE:

    Wednesday, March 13, 2024 at 16:46:41 Japan Standard Time
    
    2024-03-13T07:46:41Z


== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme “Trip Collector”
    
    Unexpected failure
    
    Run custom shell script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources':
    error: Sandbox: bash(73303) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/miran/Desktop/Trip Collector/Pods/resources-to-copy-Trip Collector.txt (in target 'Trip Collector' from project 'Trip Collector')
    /Users/miran/Desktop/Trip Collector/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Trip Collector/Pods-Trip Collector-resources.sh: line 20: /Users/miran/Desktop/Trip Collector/Pods/resources-to-copy-Trip Collector.txt: Operation not permitted
    realpath: illegal option -- m
    usage: realpath [-q] [path ...]
    :20: error: Unexpected failure
    

== VERSION INFO:

    Tools: 15E204a
    OS:    23D60
    PID:   70952
    Model: MacBook Air
    Arch:  arm64e


== ENVIRONMENT:

    openFiles = [
        /Users/miran/Desktop/Trip Collector/Trip Collector/RuleDescriptionView.swift
    ]
    wantsNewBuildSystem = true
    newBuildSystemAvailable = true
    activeScheme = Trip Collector
    activeRunDestination = iPhone 15 Pro variant iphonesimulator arm64
    workspaceArena = [x]
    buildArena = [x]
    buildableEntries = [
        Trip Collector.app
    ]
    runMode = Dynamic Replacement


== SELECTED RUN DESTINATION:

    name = iPhone 15 Pro
    eligible = true
    sdk = Optional(<DVTSDK:0x13d820770:'iphonesimulator17.4':Simulator - iOS 17.4:<DVTFilePath:0x600003cdc080:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk'>>)
    variant = Optional("iphonesimulator")
    device = Optional(<DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x13c7b96e0> {
            SimDevice: iPhone 15 Pro (119527A1-6C81-4438-BEB0-F33D52477BC3, iOS 17.4, Shutdown)
    })


== SELECTED RUN DESTINATION:

    Simulator - iOS 17.4 | iphonesimulator | arm64 | iPhone 15 Pro | no proxy


== PACKAGE RESOLUTION ERRORS:

    
== REFERENCED SOURCE PACKAGES:

    
== SESSION GROUP 5200:

    workspace identifier: WorkspaceIdentifier(identifier: 75D7E3E6-C1EB-4FE6-A88E-954A6B909155)
    providers: [
        Preview Provider | RuleDescriptionView_Previews provider #1 in RuleDescriptionView.swift [Editor(5110)]
    ]
    translation units: [
        /Users/miran/Desktop/Trip Collector/Trip Collector/RuleDescriptionView.swift
    ]
    attributes: [
        Editor(5110):     []
    ]
    session: 5201
    request sessions: [
        RuleDescriptionView_Previews provider #1 in RuleDescriptionView.swift: not completed
    ]


== UPDATE SESSION 5201:

    Start Date: Wednesday, March 13, 2024 at 16:46:21 Japan Standard Time
    Preview Provider {
        Simulator {
            platform: none
            device: 483CC7F1-D79E-4160-9580-77DE0C178E7A iPhone 15 Pro
            buildNumber: 21E213
            runtimePath: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime
        }
    }
    Build Graph {
        target app Trip Collector.app (#1)
           translationUnit RuleDescriptionView.swift (#2)
           Preview Provider | RuleDescriptionView_Previews provider #1 in RuleDescriptionView.swift [Editor(5110)] Preview Provider | RuleDescriptionView_Previews provider #1 in RuleDescriptionView.swift [Editor(5110)] (#3)
    }
    Update Plan {
        iOS [arm64 iphonesimulator17.4 iphonesimulator] (iPhone 15 Pro, 119527A1-6C81-4438-BEB0-F33D52477BC3-iphonesimulator17.4-arm64-iphonesimulator), [], thinning disabled, thunking enabled) {
            Destination: iPhone 15 Pro 119527A1-6C81-4438-BEB0-F33D52477BC3 | default device for iphonesimulator [
                Trip_Collector app - Previews {
                    execution points [
                        provider Trip_Collector.RuleDescriptionView_Previews
                    ]
                    translation units [
                        RuleDescriptionView.swift (in Trip Collector.app)
                    ]
                    modules [
                        Trip Collector.app
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

== POWER STATE LOGS:

    2024/03/13, 16:33 Received power source state: Battery Powered (lowPowerMode: false, status: unplugged, level: 80%)
    2024/03/13, 16:33 Broadcasting device power state: Mid Power
    2024/03/13, 16:33 No device power state user override user default value.Current power state: Mid Power
```